# In SAS, is "not =" a legitimate operator?

Tags: sas

I've come across a program that uses `not =` as if it had the same meaning as `ne` or `^=`.  It seems to work fine, and doesn't raise so much as a note to log.  But I can't find any official documentation confirming that this is supported syntax.

Is `not =` really the same as `ne`?

Comment: I see now that this is actually how Enterprise Guide writes its queries when you create a "not equal" filter in a query, using one of the wizards.

Comment: And now I see that `not =` is what SAS puts in the log at the end of a data step when you use a subsetting `where`, whether you use `ne` or `^=`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please refer the below link:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001001956.htm

Hope this helps

Comment: This is not a complete answer to the question.  A complete answer contains the information needed to answer the question in the text of the answer, not in a link.  See [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Look at the documentation here http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/67885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p00iah2thp63bmn1lt20esag14lh.htm

```
data _null_;
x = 1;
if x not = 0 then
    put x=;
run;
```

Comment: That's were I looked.  I see `not` being prefixed to values (`not x`) and expressions (`not(x=1)`, but I don't see any examples or descriptions of `not =`.

Comment: It is described in the same way as the `^` operator, so I take it to mean they are interchangeable.

Comment: Weird.  I always thought of `^=` as one symbol, but it looks like I might as well think of it as two concatenated.